# Micorosft Edge - Embedded PDF - How to Print

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, browser

Our site has PDF's embedded into our pages which allow the user to print them. We have this working across all browsers/platforms using various techniques PDFjs/PDFObject/iframes etc...

However when it comes to the Edge none of these techniques print properly. Using the an iframe which I assume is using the native PDF viewer there is no print option (only Save As), If I print using the Edge toolbar I get all the html content around it (I appreciate that I could hide the rest of the content using css for the print, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way). Using PDFjs prints the whole page not just the PDF. PDF Object just tells me I don't have Adobe Installed preumably because there is no ActiveX support.

So my questions are has anyone else worked out how to print out an embedded PDF in Edge yet? And if you have how?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft are aware of this issue in Edge, and are looking to introduce it in the upcoming Windows 10 Creators Update (Version 1703, AKA Redstone 2 or RS2), scheduled for Spring 2017.

As far as I can tell there is no current solution to this problem.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7801755/